# Why do people use adhoc XAI methods (e.g., SHAP, LIME) for interpretable models such as logistic regression?

Tags: regression, artificial-intelligence, shap

I completely understand why one would use methods such as SHAP or LIME to explain black box machine learning models such as random forests or neural nets. However, I see a lot of content online where people apply these types of ad-hoc XAI methods to explain inherently interpretable models such as linear SVM or logistic regression.

Is there any way benefit to using, say, LIME instead of simply looking at the regression coefficients if my aim is to explain predictions from a logistic regression? Could it perhaps have to do with interactions between features when the number of features is very high?

Answer (score 2):

I think same, interactions would be the main reason. As you can see how LIME and SHAP works from below definitions -

LIME -
Creates local data points near to the one in consideration, then creates local models by minimizing the outcomes from actual model and local model error and then makes inferences.

SHAP -
Iterate all possible subsets (sample) to see interactions, with and without feature.